Forbids something in Posix to have an empty string as a file name?
My experience is that trying to do anything with an empty string filename results file not found (ENOENT), including a ls -ld '', touch '' or mkdir ''. But I could try only ext4.
While it looks quite logical to me, does it something in the Posix what would forbid that?

The 3.170 point of the Unix spec states that a filename cannot be empty:

A sequence of bytes consisting of 1 to {NAME_MAX} bytes used to name a
file. The bytes composing the name shall not contain the <NUL> or
<slash> characters.

So trying to operate on an empty filename will give an error. I would suggest testing if string is empty before trying to operate on it.

Nice work, fine! Actually, my goal is not debugging, but the better conscience of such a trivial, but easily overlooked edge case.

Another interesting feature, if it would be allowed, then a zero-length filename could be a way to keep file data about its parent directory itself. But not this is the case as a zero-length filename would break standard, i.e. it would not be pretty unix any more.

Fun fact: a long time (~40 years) ago, the null string was functionally an alias for the current directory. I don’t recall ever seeing that documented. It felt more like a bug — or at least an “oops, but we don’t care that that happened” — than a design feature.
